# JBake Freemarker errror "this has evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence"

Tags: freemarker, jbake

Given a `jbake.properties` with:

```
description: OptaPlanner optimizes business resource usage. It is a lightweight, embeddable, open source planning engine, written in 100% Java.
```

And a template with:

```
<meta property="description" content="${config.description}">
```

Freemarker throws this error

```
this has evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to escape the `,` in `jbake.properties`:

```
description: OptaPlanner optimizes business resource usage. It is a lightweight\\, embeddable\\, open source planning engine\\, written in 100% Java.
```